# What are the advantages of adding more repositories to one's sources.list?

Tags: linux, software-installation, repository, distributions

I wondered that whether it is a real matter (not only in special cases) to have more than the default repositories *installed*.

I mean, on the one hand, there's the Linux kernel, with just the fundamental basic system and there is Free Software added which, combined, leads to a Linux Distro.

On the other hand, I can hardly imagine a distro not just for a few dozens of people not having the hundereds (or thousands?) of packages included you get with a "major" Distro. I mean, even wine can be found in standard Distro package lists and they have also their ["own repository"](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/).

Comment: The standard distros don't always have the most up to date packages and sometimes doesn't contain certain "niche" packages that may be required. The epel repo is an example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At lot of packages (and their dependencies) that you may want/need aren't available from the standard distro.

You could of course download them, compile from source, matching all dependencies yourself. Or you can add the repo and let your package manager worry about sorting that out, i guess that's the big advantage.

A good example of a repo i usually end up adding on my systems is the epel repo.  I think its name explains what is does `Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux`.